# Reading the folder and give the details of all the files present in the folder

Tags: java

I was given a program which should read all the files present in a given folder and give the file details such as file name, file size, created date and time, file location as output. If there any subfolders in the given folder, then it should geive the details of the files present in that subfolder too.

Comment: There is an API for that in standard Java library. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You can use `File.list()` method take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)

Answer (score 0):

```
package FileDetails;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;``


public class FileDetails 
{
    public static void filelist(final File folder) throws IOException
    {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())
        {
            if(fileEntry.isDirectory())
            {
                filelist(fileEntry);
            }
            else
            {
                //To get file name

                System.out.println("File name is : " + fileEntry.getName());

                //To get file extension

                String fileName = fileEntry.getName();
                if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Extension of file is : " + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1));
                }

                //To get file size

                double bytes = fileEntry.length();
                double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
                System.out.println("Size of the file is : " + kilobytes + " KB");

                //To get file times

                Path path = fileEntry.toPath();
                BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(path,BasicFileAttributes.class);

                System.out.println("Creation time  :  " + attr.creationTime());
                System.out.println("Last Access time  :  " + attr.lastAccessTime());
                System.out.println("Last Modified time  :  " + attr.lastModifiedTime() + "\n\n");


            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException
    {
        final File folder = new File("folder location");
        filelist(folder);
    }
}
```